# Tab widget size issue on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: tabs, jupyter-notebook, widget, jupyter, tabwidget

I am having a issue with size of the second graph added to the tab widget, which is not of the size of all the container:
here is by code

```
''' output_co2 = widgets.Output()
output_co = widgets. Output()

tab = widgets.Tab(children=[output_co2, output_co],
                  layout=widgets.Layout(width='100%', height='100%'))
tab.set_title(0, 'CO2')
tab.set_title(1, 'CO')
display(tab)

with output_co2:
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=vehicleData['distance_m']/1000,
                             y=vehicleData['co_gs'],
                             name='CO [g/s]',
                             mode="lines",
                             line=dict(
                                       width=2),
    fig.show()
with output_co:
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=vehicleData['distance_m']/1000,
                             y=vehicleData['co_gs'],
                             name='CO [g/s]',
                             mode="lines",
                             line=dict(
                                       width=2),
     fig.show() '''
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID1BB.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViZMO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With plotly you need to use the `go.FigureWidget()` in place of `go.Figure()`, see [here](https://plotly.com/python/figurewidget/).  So something like this:

```py
output_co2 = widgets.Output()
output_co = widgets.Output()

tab = widgets.Tab(children=[output_co2, output_co])
tab.set_title(0, 'CO2')
tab.set_title(1, 'CO')
display(tab)

with output_co2:
    fig = go.FigureWidget() # HERE
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=vehicleData['distance_m']/1000,
                             y=vehicleData['co_gs'],
                             name='CO [g/s]',
                             mode="lines",
                             line_width=2))
    fig.show()

with output_co:
    fig = go.FigureWidget() # AND HERE
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=vehicleData['distance_m']/1000,
                             y=vehicleData['co_gs'],
                             name='CO [g/s]',
                             mode="lines",
                             line_width=2))
    fig.show()
```

Alternative:
With plotly you can use `go.FigureWidget()` directly instead of `widgets.Output()`

```py
fig1 = go.FigureWidget()
fig2 = go.FigureWidget()

tab = widgets.Tab(children=[fig1, fig2])
tab.set_title(0, 'CO2')
tab.set_title(1, 'CO')

fig1.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=vehicleData['distance_m']/1000,
                             y=vehicleData['co_gs'],
                             mode="lines",
                             line_width=2))

fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=vehicleData['distance_m']/1000,
                             y=vehicleData['co_gs'],
                             mode="lines",
                             line_width=2))
display(tab)
```